# Handling non-consumable in-app purchases when a user can log in and out of the app

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have recently had an iOS app rejected by Apple for using a consumable IAP item to upgrade a 'user' from silver to gold, whereas according to Apple guidelines it should be a non-consumable item. However, our reasoning for using a consumable item is as follows:

- The app has its own user authentication system, tied to a backend. As soon as the consumable is purchased, the user object is modified to a gold type. So by default their purchase will be available on other devices, providing they login with the correct app user.
- If we were to use a non-consumable type it would be possible for a user to purchase an upgrade and proceed to logout of the app, log back in as a different 'app' user, hit restore transactions button (required if the app is using non-consumables) and upgrade another user to gold for free.

What is the correct approach in situations like this? The way I see it, we have the following options:

1. Change to non-consumable to keep Apple happy, accept that there is a possibility that users might be able to upgrade multiple accounts for free. Although it is probably unlikely in reality that this will happen that much
2. Stick with consumable and alter some of the wording around our purchase type, to make it more clear that it is something that you could potentially purchase again in the future if you switch app user. Or even go as far as to have a kind of in-app currency (seems overkill for an app with only one purchase type)

Am I missing something, this seems to be a grey area with little information available. Essentially we don't want to tie upgrades to an AppleID we want them to be tied to an app user. Is there any way that we can implement a non-consumable but also prevent users being able to upgrade multiple accounts? Alternatively how can we manipulate the purchase event in such a way so that consumable is considered appropriate?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the resores also access your backend can't you resrict the number of times this is done for a user based on associating receipts with users?

Comment: In the end Apple made us switch over to using a non-consumable purchase. Slightly annoying as there is now a loophole where a user can potentially purchase the upgrade, sign out and sign in as a different app user - opt to restore their purchases and get a free account upgrade for a different app user. We may look at altering the wording (or switch to purchasing in-app tokens) at some point so that apple allow the purchase type to be consumable

Comment: what did you end up doing with this? i'm running into similar issues with my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you use serverside receipt validation you can store the original transaction id of the purchase with the useraccount on you server.

When a user buys the non-consumeble check on the server if the original transaction id exist in your DB for a different user